# Contar letras repetidas en un string c#

Tags: c#, string

estoy haciendo un ejercicio para clase, en el que tengo que contar las letras que se repiten en un string (Sin que el usuario de nada, simplemente contar las letras del mismo string, las veces que se repiten), pero no consigo hacer que me muestre por pantalla, cada letra una sola vez, es decir, me muestra el string entero, y yo solo quiero que me aparezca una vez cada letra. Además, tengo que hacer una comparación para que las letras en minúscula y mayúscula sean lo mismo, y no consigo hacer un .toupper, a ver si alguien puede echarme alguna ayuda, aquí el código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("exercici1.txt")) {
                    string line;
                    char caracter = ' ';
                    int compt = 0;

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < line.Length; x++)
                        {

                            for (int y = 0; y < line.Length; y++)
                            {
                                caracter = line[x];
                                if (caracter == line[y])
                                {
                                    compt++;
                                }
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("El caracter " + caracter + " apareix " + compt + " vegades");
                            compt = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error general");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cual es el contenido del archivo? y cual es la salida que arroja?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Llevar la cuenta de los caracteres encontrados

El principal problema es que no llevas registro de que caracteres has encontrado.

Así, por ejemplo, si tomas la cadena "aaa", en tu bucle...

```
for (int x = 0; x < line.Length; x++)
{
    // ...
}
```

Te encuentras conque `line[x]` es `'a'` en la primera iteración, y luego es `'a'` en la segunda, y nuevamente `'a'` en la tercera.

Necesitas llevar la cuenta de que caracteres has encontrado.

Veamos que estructura de datos te sirve...

- El orden no importa (no vas a mostrar al usuario el contenido).
- Necesitas encontrar elementos por valor (el carácter).
- No tendrá duplicados (no vas a agregar un carácter dos veces)

Lo que necesitas es un [Conjunto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunto_(programaci%C3%B3n)).

.NET nos ofrece [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) y [`SortedSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx). Cualquiera de los dos sirve.

Estas son las diferencias:

- `HashSet<T>` existe desde .NET 3.5, y `SortedSet<T>` was introduces in .NET 4.0
- `HashSet<T>` es compacta en memoria, `SortedSet<T>` no lo es.
- `SortedSet<T>` mantiene el orden de los datos. `HashSet<T>` no.

Nota: tu no necesitas mantener el orden de los datos. Es trabajo adicional que haría el computador innecesariamente, y es una funcionalidad que tendrías que mantener (usar `IComparer`).

---

**¿Porque no usar un arreglo o un `string`?**

Porque la búsqueda sobre un arreglo o un `string` ocurre en tiempo lineal (`O(n)`), es decir que el computador tiene que comparar elemento por elemento. Es menos eficiente que buscar sobre un conjunto que tiene tiempo logarítmico (`O(log n)`).

Presumo que esto es irrelevante para ti, bajo el supuesto que el tamaño de los datos de entrada en pequeño.

Lo que tiempo lineal y tiempo logarítmico significa es que el tiempo que tarda el computador en realizar la búsqueda es una función lineal (el computador tarda x milisegundos adicionales por cada elemento guardado) o logarítmica (el computador tarda x milisegundos adicionales por cada orden de magnitud de los elementos guardados).

---

Hay una razón adicional para no utilizar un arreglo. Y es que es una estructura de tamaño fijo. Requeriría que supieras de antemano cuantos caracteres distintos vas a encontrar... o la hagas suficientemente grande para el peor de los casos (considerando Unicode, estaríamos hablando de más de un millón de elementos).

---

Hay una razón adicional para no utilizar `string`. Y es que los `string` son inmutables. Tu en realidad no modificas un `string`, sino que creas uno nuevo cada vez que haces una operación. Eso significa que cada vez que concatenas un carácter estás creando un `string` nuevo.

Este proceso crea basura innecesariamente.

De nuevo, esto no es un problema si el tamaño de la entrada es pequeño (los computadores modernos tienen gran cantidad de memoria, al fin y al cabo). Sin embargo, es algo que vale la pena saber.

---

### Comparar ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas

Lo otro que mencionas es que tienes que hacer que la comparación no distinga mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Para esto puedes utilizar [ToUpper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.toupper(v=vs.110).aspx) sin embargo no te lo recomiendo. La razón es que la conversión de mayúsculas y minúsculas no es igual en todos los lenguajes. El ejemplo para este caso es el Turco, en el cual la versión mayúsculas de `i` es `İ`en lugar de `I`.

Por supuesto, tu no estás pensando en que tu código tenga que funcionar en un computador en Turco. Sin embargo, es buena practica tener en cuenta las diferencias culturales al manejar strings.

Addenum: para el español `Ñ` es una letra distinta a `N`, para otros idiomas es una `N` con una marca diacrítica.

Hay seis soluciones:

- Usar `ToUpper` y asumir que todas las comparaciones son el idioma del computador. Lo cual puede ocultar algún defecto que pueda aparecer cuando tu programa tenga que ejecutarse en otra parte del mundo.
- Usar `ToUpper` y especificar la cultura. Esto es, utilizar la sobre carga de `ToUpper` que recibe `CultureInfo` como segundo parámetro.
- Usar `ToUpperInvariant`, que ignora las reglas especificas del idioma.
- No cambiar mayúsculas, en su lugar convertir a `string` y utilizar `String.Compare`. Que tiene sobre cargas que reciben `ignoreCase` para comparar ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas.
- No cambiar mayúsculas, en su lugar convertir a `string` y utilizar `String.Compare`. Que además tiene sobre cargas que reciben `CultureInfo` en caso que quieras especificarlo.
- No cambiar mayúsculas, en su lugar convertir a `string` y utilizar `String.CompareOrdinal`. Que tiene sobre cargas que reciben `ignoreCase` para comparar ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Ahora, entre `Ordinal` e `Invariant`, tienes que contestar una pregunta: son `á` y `A` la misma letra? Tus requerimiento hablan de mayúsculas, pero no de acentos. Y estos son caracteres diferentes. Si tu programa debe tratar `a` y `á` por separado tu quieres una comparación `Ordinal`.

---

### Integrando la solución

Ok, ya habíamos elegimos estructura de datos. Es un `HashSet<T>`. Necesitamos decirle que no tenga en cuenta mayúsculas y minúsculas. Debido a que lo que `HashSet<T>` recibe es un `IEqualityComparer<T>`, diría que uses `StringComparer` y de esa forma te ahorras implementar esa interfaz.

También debemos trabajar entorno al inconveniente que `HashSet<T>` espera una colección si queremos paras un  `IEqualityComparer<T>`. Esto no es problema, podemos pasar un arreglo vacío.

Luego el código sería:

```
var conjunto = new HashSet<string>(new string[]{}, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

O

```
var conjunto = new HashSet<string>(new string[]{}, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

O

```
var conjunto = new HashSet<string>(new string[]{}, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Dependiendo si quieres comparación ordinal (`OrdinalIgnoreCase`), o si no, pero quieres ignorar reglas especificas del lenguaje (`InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`), o quieres usar las reglas especificas del lenguaje actual (`CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`).

---

Luego puedes utilizar [`conjunto.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb356440(v=vs.110).aspx) para verificar si un elemento ha sido agregado. Y por supuesto [`conjunto.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx) para agregar.

Observa que `conjunto.Add` devuelve `bool`. Este valor te dice si el elemento es nuevo. Lo que te puede ahorrar algunas lineas de código.

---

Por ultimo, tus bucles son iguales:

```
for (int x = 0; x < line.Length; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < line.Length; y++)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Ambos empiezan al inicio de la linea (`0`) y terminan al final de la linea (`line.Length`).

Esto significa que vas a empezar comparando el primer carácter `line[x]` con el primer carácter `line[y]` porque en la primera iteración tanto `x` como `y` son `0` (`int x = 0` e `int y = 0`).

Deberías solo comparar con los caracteres siguientes al al actual (porque los anteriores ya los comparaste).

Nota: estoy asumiendo que debes hacer los conteos linea por linea del archivo.

---

Con los cambios mencionado, este sería el código a utilizar:

```
string line;
string caracter;
int compt = 0;
var comparador = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var conjunto = new HashSet<string>(new string[]{}, comparador);
    for (int x = 0; x < line.Length; x++)
    {
        caracter = line[x].ToString();
        if (conjunto.Add(caracter))
        {
            var compt = 1; // <--- ya lo encontré, lo coloco en 1
            for (int y = x + 1; y < line.Length; y++)
            {
                if (comparador.Equals(caracter, line[y].ToString()))
                {
                    compt++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("El caracter " + caracter + " apareix " + compt + " vegades");
        }
    }
}
```

Notas:

- He cambiado `caracter` a tipo `string`. La razón es que estamos haciendo las comparaciones a nivel de `string`. Esto debido a que estamos utilizando `StringComparer` (no hay un `CharComparer` disponible en el BCL, y he preferido no explicar como implementar `IEqualityComparer<char>`, esta respuesta ya es suficientemente larga como está).
- Al usar `string` además dejar `caracter` sin inicializar. No es lo que lo necesite, sin embargo no tiene sentido darle valor alguno.
- He sacado `comparador` aparte, para poder utilizarlo al contar caracteres. Tiene sentido que se cuenten de la misma forma que se verifica si ya se ha encontrado.
- Estoy iniciando `y` en `x + 1`, de forma que `y` solo revisa a partir del siguiente carácter del que se encuentra `x`.
- No tenia sentido dar valor a `caracter` en cada ciclo de `y`. Solo tiene sentido dar valor a `caracter` cuando `x` cambia. Por esta razón lo he sacado del bucle interno.
- Dentro del bucle, ya que el carácter actual lo he encontrado, puedo iniciar el conteo en `1`.
- Observa como se crea `conjunto` y como se utiliza `Add` en un `if`.

De hecho, creo que puedo mejorar aun más el código...

```
var comparador = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;

while ((var line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var conjunto = new HashSet<string>(new string[]{}, comparador);
    for (int x = 0; x < line.Length; x++)
    {
        var caracter = line[x].ToString();
        if (conjunto.Add(caracter))
        {
            var compt = 1; // <--- ya lo encontré, lo coloco en 1
            for (int y = x + 1; y < line.Length; y++)
            {
                if (comparador.Equals(caracter, line[y].ToString()))
                {
                    compt++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"El caracter {caracter} apareix {compt} vegades");
        }
    }
}
```

Tomando ventaja de características modernas de C#.

Nota: no he probado este código.

---

### Una alternativa

Todo lo anterior ha sido bajo el supuesto que debes reportar los caracteres en el orden que los encuentras... si no es así... puedes guardar en una estructura de datos cuantas veces has encontrado un carácter. De forma que recorres el `string` una sola vez (tendrías un solo bucle para recorrer el `string`, en lugar de dos bucles anidados), agregando al conteo cada carácter que encuentras.

Veamos que estructura de datos te sirve...

- El tal vez importa (vas a mostrar al usuario el contenido)
- Necesitas encontrar elementos por llave (el carácter)
- No tendrá duplicados (no vas a agregar un carácter dos veces)
- Necesitas llave (el carácter) y valor (el conteo).

La estructura de datos es un diccionario. Tenemos `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` y `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. En esta variante del código, vas a mostrar el contenido de la estructura de datos... yo voy a asumir que el orden no importa, puesto que hace las cosas un poco más fáciles.

---

```
while ((var line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var diccionario = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    for (int x = 0; x < line.Length; x++)
    {
        var caracter = line[x].ToString();
        if (diccionario.ContainsKey(caracter))
        {
            diccionario[caracter] ++;
        }
        else
        {
            diccionario.Add(caracter, 1);
        }
    }
    foreach (var entrada in diccionario)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"El caracter {entrada.Key} apareix {entrada.Value} vegades");
    }
}
```

Notas:

- Ya no necesito comparar para contar caracteres, así que no necesito declarar la variable `comparador`.
- Cuando encuentro un carácter, verifico si ya está en el diccionario. Si es así, le incremento el valor. Si no está, lo agrego con valor `1`.

---

### Separación de preocupaciones

Tu código se encarga de tres operaciones:

- Acceder y leer el archivo
- Procesar las cadenas de caracteres
- Mostrar el resultado al usuario

Si en el futuro llegas a necesitar procesar varios archivos, o tal vez procesar la entrada del usuario etc... te conviene separar estas operaciones.

Si en el futuro llegas a necesitar hacer que este código funcione en una página web o en un formulario, etc... te conviene separar estas operaciones.

Incluso, simplemente si quieres cambiar el idioma del software, no deberías tener que modificar el código que se dedica a contar caracteres.

Por supuesto, esto es un trabajo académico, y esas cosas no van a pasar (o tal vez si, dependiendo del docente). Sin embargo, es algo que te vas a encontrar en muchas formas (comúnmente con la base de datos) si llegas a trabajar como programador.

Así que te sugiero separar esas operaciones. ¿Cual es el criterio? Sencillo: Aislar el código que se encarga de interactuar con sistemas externos (e.g. el sistema de archivo, la consola) de forma tal que se comunique con el resto del software intercambiando valores (e.g. las cadenas de texto).

Esto además hace que el código sea más fácil de probar. Por ejemplo yo puedo probar el código que se encarga de contar caracteres sin necesidad de usar un archivo.

Otra ventaja es que facilita dividir el trabajo entre varios programadores. Así uno se puede encargar de mostrar los mensajes al usuario, otro de trabajar con archivos y otro de procesar el texto. Tal vez no te suene a una división equitativa, pero es una forma de dividir que impide que "se pisen las margueras" y es - asumiendo que todos saben lo que hacen - es más rápido que dejar todo el trabajo lo haga una sola persona.

A mi solo me interesa poder probar el código para contar caracteres (para poder poner una respuesta con confianza de que funciona), así que lo voy a extraer. Y me voy a limitar a eso. Este es el código:

```
while ((var line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var diccionario = ContarCaracteres(line);
    foreach (var entrada in diccionario)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"El caracter {entrada.Key} apareix {entrada.Value} vegades");
    }
}

// ...

static Dictionary<string, int> ContarCaracteres(string line)
{
    var diccionario = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    for (int x = 0; x < line.Length; x++)
    {
        var caracter = line[x].ToString();
        if (diccionario.ContainsKey(caracter))
        {
            diccionario[caracter] ++;
        }
        else
        {
            diccionario.Add(caracter, 1);
        }
    }
    return diccionario;
}
```

*He probado el código de ContarCaracteres. Puedo decir que funciona.*

---

**Addendum**

Flxtr tiene un punto importante (aparte de Linq): Podemos tomar la cadena y convertirla a mayúsculas (con `ToUpper` o `ToUpperInvariant`) y luego convertirla a un arreglo de caracteres (con `ToCharArray`) de forma que podemos comparar directamente los caracteres sin necesidad de `StringComparer`.

Esta solución es más eficiente (debido a que no tenemos que usar `ToString` carácter por carácter):

```
static Dictionary<char, int> ContarCaracteres(string line)
{
    var diccionario = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (var caracter in line.ToUpperInvariant().ToCharArray())
    {
        if (diccionario.ContainsKey(caracter))
        {
            diccionario[caracter] ++;
        }
        else
        {
            diccionario.Add(caracter, 1);
        }
    }
    return diccionario;
}
```

Comment: Buen análisis y más para este caso que es un ejercicio académico.
Es un claro ejemplo de como un problema que suena sencillo puede llegar a ser verdaderamente complejo.

Comment: Brutal explicación y análisis, muchísimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 5):

Una manera elegante y rápida de resolverlo es usando Linq:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string cadena = "HHhhola, soy una cadena con caracteres repetidos";

    Console.WriteLine(cadena + "\n\n");

    var result = from a in cadena.ToUpper().ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsLetter)
                 group a by a into g
                 select new
                 {
                     Letra = g.Key,
                     Repeticiones = g.Count()
                 };


    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("El caracter {0} apareix {1} vegades", item.Letra, item.Repeticiones));
    }
}
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

> HHhhola, soy una cadena con caracteres repetidos
>
> El caracter H apareix 4 vegades
>
> El caracter o apareix 4 vegades
>
> El caracter l apareix 1 vegades
>
> El caracter a apareix 6 vegades
>
> El caracter s apareix 3 vegades
>
> El caracter y apareix 1 vegades
>
> El caracter u apareix 1 vegades
>
> El caracter n apareix 3 vegades
>
> El caracter c apareix 4 vegades
>
> El caracter d apareix 2 vegades
>
> El caracter e apareix 5 vegades
>
> El caracter r apareix 3 vegades
>
> El caracter t apareix 2 vegades
>
> El caracter p apareix 1 vegades
>
> El caracter i apareix 1 vegades

Básicamente el funcionamiento es, convertir la cadena a mayúsculas, luego a un `array`, agrupar el contenido de ese `array` por cada letra y finalmente seleccionar la letra y el número de repeticiones.

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración de la solución](http://rextester.com/TIPH50015)</kbd>

**Actualización:**

Se omite la conversión a `.ToString()` ya que no era necesaria.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que puedes hacer es ir guardando la letra que ya revisaste para que no vuelva a ser contada. Puedes utilizar un `array` o `string`.

Modificando tu código quedaría así:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("exercici1.txt")) {
                    string line;
                    char caracter = ' ';
                    int compt = 0;

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string checkd = "";

                        for (int x = 0; x < line.Length; x++)
                        {
                            if(!checkd.Contains(line[x].ToString())) //Revisa si la letra ya ha sido contada
                            {
                                for (int y = 0; y < line.Length; y++)
                                {
                                    caracter = line[x];
                                    if (caracter == line[y])
                                    {
                                        compt++;
                                    }
                                }
                                Console.WriteLine("El caracter " + caracter + " apareix " + compt + " vegades");
                                compt = 0;

                                checkd += line[x].ToString(); // Almacena la letra contada
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error general");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```